# jQuery Intellisense in VS2012

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

How can I add a plugin into Visual Studio 2012 to work with jQuery syntax in intellisense on visual studio?

Please don't give me link of other site, just give a solution that you did and worked fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Install NuGet in Visual Studio Extension Manager
2. Open your web application solution
3. Open **Package Manager Console** from Tools-> Library Package Manager,
   NuGet add latest jQuery versions to your project
4. Type "PM> Install-Package jQuery" in console
5. Drag and drop your jQuery script file from the Solution Explorer window onto the javascript editor window
6. Enjoy jQuery intellisense

Comment: I tried it but got `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.` error

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2012 provides JQuery intellisence out of the box without the need for additional plugins... to get this functionality, simply drag the _references.js file from with teh scripts folder into the .js file you are working on.. it will place a  tag into the top of the file for you and provide intellisense.

Im presuming you are using as ASP.NET / MVC project template.

Comment: Take a look at the references file.. its just a a file filled with all the script references... just download jQuery 1.8 using nuget or something and drag the JQuery.debug.js file (or whatever its called) into the _references file to update it.]

Answer (score 0):

You can reference Jquery intellisense file (jquery-1.12.4.intellisense.js) in your page and then it will start working.