# RE: implementing rest / jquery with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

Hi I've had a look around but I can't find any simple answers to this basic question I have.

I understand using HTML you can reference scripts using the script tag.

My question is in using Javascript must you reference a jquery library and rest API to be able to use them like in HTML or do i just reference them in HTML web parts (from sharepoint) as i would normally do? script tag referencing a js file (and potentially?? jquery and REST)?

Comment: what is this "rest api" you talk about?

Comment: A rest api is generally referenced by making ajax calls. You can do that with jQuery, or just the XMLHttpRequest object in straight JavaScript. Also, if your question is about SharePoint programming, you should probably tag it as such.

Comment: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html (it's not about SharePoint i just want to know how I can get my visual studio's intellisense to pickup Jquery and idk if i need to say in my js file "hey im able to use jquery here")

Comment: Well, again tags help. Nothing in your question mentioned visual studio or intellisense. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359090/jquery-intellisense-in-vs2012

Comment: yeah it didn't need to ^^ I only really want to know what I asked :p which is why I asked what I did rather than the life story of why I want to know it :D

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to my question is that it's called within the js file. I was thinking of it like it was C# dev with references that you just call when you need them rather than having everything there all of the time.